# Redirect to page passing token and refreshing all routes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, send

I'm a beginner in React. I need to pass a token to the app component, so I can render all components.

How can I "redirect" with a token to main App? I used this page to receive information from a service that sent the user id login:

```
 class SocialVerify extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
    let token = this.props.match.params.id;
    fetch('/api/account/social?token=' + token)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            if (json.success) {
                setInStorage('the_main_app', {token: token});
                this.setState({token: token, obj: true});
                //How i do "redirect" with token to identify a user login? I used this page to receive information from a service that sent the user id loggin             

            }
        });
 }
```

I have a componentWillmountthat checks whether token exists or not, if it exists it renders all components with state token.

In signin works because the token obj, is passed by state by the components.

In this case the socialverify component is an external component, it is only used to treat information received from a service. In this case Facebook. 
The objective is to pass the socialverify token to the app e executar o componentDidmount in App with this token.

```
   class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
            token: '',
      }
   }
   componentDidMount() {

         const obj = getFromStorage('the_main_app');
   //Here I would like to receive the token, and in this case of social login the obj was the token             
          if (obj && obj.token) {
              //Verify token
              this.setState({
                   token: obj.token,
              });
          }
   }
    render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
            <Route path="/socialverify/:id" component={SocialVerify}/>
            <Header IDtoken={this.state.token} Refresh={(token) => this.setState({token: token})}/>
            <main>
                <Route exact path="/:id" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/acc_reset/:id" component={NewPassword}/>
            </main>
        </Switch>
        </div>)
     }
}
```